# Proper use of Win32 Device Context

Tags: c++, msdn

I have been working with GDI for a time now and I am trying to up my understanding of it to be able to create a wrapper class for it.

1. Why cant I hold on to a window device context until the app ends? Does it get invalidated upon any of the events? I heard someone say after WM_SIZE the context gets invalidated, is this true? I never experienced this even though I always cache the window context. It makes it much easier to createCompatibleDC()s and createCompatibleBitmaps()s in the constructor. I also cache these created DC and use them to avoid flickering, for local bounds drawing, caching the draw operation incase window is minimized then maximized.
2. Why would an application ever fetch more than 1 window context at a time? As the documemtation complains about running out the window context limit.

Comment: Regarding your second question, you could for example have one DC to draw on, and the blit it to the window DC. This prevents flicker when drawing directly on the window DC.

Comment: Depends on how the DC was created.  If you got it from BeginPaint() then you'll regret caching it, the clipping region easily gets stale.  GetDC() is okay.  Caching is useful if creating an object is expensive but storage is cheap.  A window DC is cheap to create but stored in the very limited desktop heap.  Caching just one isn't anything to worry about.

Comment: @Hans I am not in the habit of caching or using multiple window contexts, but how much before my system slows? I accidentally discovered that constantly creating Bitmaps without freeing slows down your app very noticeably very quickly. Which means Bitmaps are very memory expensive.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, my second question is strictly about window dc and not memory dc.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in the context you are talking about 'invalidate' means to require some portion of the window to be redrawn, it does not mean that a handle retrieved from GetDC will be rendered unusable.

A window with CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW will require at least partial redrawing on any resize in the indicated direction as well as any sizing operation that increases the window size.

Because of the limitations on the number of GDI objects the normal pattern is to handle WM_PAINT messages and use the handle returned by BeginPaint (which will only remain usable so long as EndPaint is not called).

And as Some programmer dude said in a comment, a second DC can be used to perform flicker-free drawing, the time consuming drawing is done to an off-screen DC and then simply copied onto the screen DC. And even if that is done entirely within a WM_PAINT handler the off-screen DC will normally be released once the drawing operation completes so as to not hog GDI resources.

Comment: great. It is confirmed that a window dc doesnt implicitly get invalidated while I am caching. Programming graphics is a comprimize in speed vs memory usage. are you saying that it is fast enough to create memory dc and get window dc, and the consequences of storing/hagging the resources is much worse? And a second question. Is open gl or directx graphics objects as memory intensive as gdi? I already know that opengl context is derived from gdi context.

Comment: Seems like that should be a new question, I do not know the answer to that off hand. I am blind and use GDI because it (particularly for text) works very nicely with accessibility tools where DirectX and OpenGL both require implementing either MSAA or UIA handlers in order for my screen reader to know about text.